# Diffeomorphisms of the circle and its lifts.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, dynamical-systems

I would like to know what is understood by $f:\mathbb{S}^1\rightarrow\mathbb{S}^1$ ($\mathbb{S}^1$ is the unit circle) being a diffeomorphism, in [this context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denjoy's_theorem_on_rotation_number).

Does differentiability on $\mathbb{S}^1$ mean that there exists an open set $U$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $\mathbb{S}^1\subseteq U$ and $f$ differentiable on $U$?

If we consider a lift $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ of $f$, is it true that $F$ is a diffeomorphism if and only if $f$ is a diffeomorphism?

Answer (score 1):

Differentiability means (*or is equivalent to*, since there are various possible definitions, all equivalent) **differentiability of some lift** (and so of all lifts).

Comment: And, for example, is continuity of $f$ defined as continuity with the distance of $\mathbb{R}^2$ restricted to $\mathbb{S}^1$ or as continuity of $F$?

Comment: The two are equivalent. But you should really think of $S^1$ by itself, not as a subset of $\mathbb R^2$.